# Bitwise Operations in Ada

Tags: bit-manipulation, ada

Is there a tutorial somewhere that explains on which datatypes bitwise operations can be used? I don't know why Lady Ada thinks that I cannot bitwise OR two Standard.Integer...

```
$ gnatmake test.adb
gcc -c test.adb
test.adb:50:77: there is no applicable operator "Or" for type "Standard.Integer"
gnatmake: "test.adb" compilation error
```

Really? I excused the compiler for not being able to AND/OR enumerated data types. I excused the compiler for not being able to perform bitwise operations on Character type. I excused the compiler for not being able to convert from Unsigned_8 to Character in what I thought was the obvious way. But this is inexcusable.

Comment: You probably haven't found a bug, but you should read this nonetheless. http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: If you see something you don't understand in a programming language, your first assumption should not be that the designers were idiots.

Comment: I was using Natural type which is a subtype of Integer, which surprisingly results in the error. Although you're putting words in my mouth by writing that I said the designers were idiots, I'm more inclined to think that the designers thought it was too complex to be able to translate the code to something like orl %eax, %ecx. I don't know why, of course. C doesn't complain.

Comment: Implementing bitwise operators for integer would not have been difficult at all. C has the philosophy of letting the programmer do anything that *might* make sense. Ada's philosophy is more about catching errors as early as possible. You can do bitwise operations on integers in Ada; you just can't do it the particular way you're trying to do it. Ada is not just C with `{` and `}` replaced by `begin` and `end`; it's a different language, and you'll have much better luck with it if you try to approach it on its own terms.

Comment: You're right, as I've only just realised. This was a major pain in the ass when I was writing my own interface to OpenGL (there aren't any good ones out there that follow the Ada naming convention Like_This), and I made enumerated data types for things like GL_RGBA just like it was in C, only to find that I cannot bitwise OR GL_RGBA with other GL_*...  I had to do some nonsense like GL_RGBA'Enum_Rep or some Unchecked_Conversion nonsense. Constants is the only way to go.

Comment: Arjun - take a look at Lumen. It is quite good OpenGL interface.
https://github.com/karakalo/lumen
https://github.com/karakalo/lumen-demos
You should visit #Ada channel at IRC and ask there before starting to write your own ;) Especially that there are at least 3 bindings that are using Ada naming conventions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ada doesn't provide logical (bit-wise) operations on integer types, it provides them on [modular types](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-4.html). Here's the [section in the reference manual](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-5-1.html).

Answer (score 15):

The `"and"`, `"or"`, and `"xor"` operators are defined for `Boolean`, for modular types, and for one-dimensional arrays of `Boolean`.

The language *could* have defined them for signed integer types, but that would create confusion given the variety of ways that signed integers can be represented. (Most implementations use two's-complement, but there are other possibilities.)

If you insist, you could define your own overloaded `"or"` operator, such as:

```
function "or"(Left, Right: Integer) return Integer is
    type Unsigned_Integer is mod 2**Integer'Size;
begin
    return Integer(Unsigned_Integer(Left) or Unsigned_Integer(Right));
end "or";
```

(I've verified that this compiles, but I haven't tested it, and I'd expect it to fail for negative values.)

But if you need to perform bitwise operations, you're better off using modular types or arrays of `Boolean` rather than signed integers.

Comment: Or use two Unsigned_Integers while specifying their addresses to be Left'Address and Right'Address, respectively and do your `OR` on them.

Comment: [Here's a test program](https://gist.github.com/Lucretia/3799b2f6961d99cf55cf9a6bbf53ee20) which *seems* to work using Keith's view conversion type.