# Ada: How to write overload for "or" operator?

Tags: generics, boolean, overloading, ada

I have been told that Ada supports "or" between boolean values. My goal is to be able to write an overload for this function using generics that supports integer types 0 and 1. (I know I can add them to get return value: if sum >= 1, return 1, else return 0) I just don't know what this would look like code wise. Here is an example of how my teacher wants it to look, here the "*" is overloaded:

```
generic
    type MyType is private;
    with function "*"(x,y: MyType) return MyType;
    with procedure Put(x: MyType);
package gioex is
    type Rectangle is
    record
        Length: MyType;
        Width: MyType;
    end record;
    function Size(r: in Rectangle) return MyType;
    function RectLength(r: in Rectangle) return MyType;
end gioex;
```

procedure Put(...) and function "*"(...) were not defined in the body of the generic, but instead in the program file:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_io;
with GIOEX;

procedure UseGioex2 is
    package MyIntIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(Integer);
    package MyFloatIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO(Float);

    type VenusMeasure is record
        F1: Integer;
        F2: Float;
    end record;

   -- Define I/O for VenusMeasurement.
   procedure Put(v: VenusMeasure) is
   begin
      MyIntIO.put(v.F1);
      put(" ");
      MyFloatIO.put(v.F2);
      new_line;
   end;

   -- Define mutliplication for VenusMeasurement.   
   function "*"(p1: VenusMeasure; p2: VenusMeasure) 
return VenusMeasure is
      temp: VenusMeasure;
   begin
      temp.F1 := p1.F1 * p2.F1;
      temp.F2 := p1.F2 * p2.F2;
      return temp;
   end;

   package MyVenusRectangle 
is new GIOEX(VenusMeasure, Put, "*");
   use MyVenusRectangle;

   width: VenusMeasure := ( 5, 5.5);
   height: VenusMeasure := (3, 2.4);

   Rect1: Rectangle := (width, height);  -- Creates a rectangle using
                                                             -- Venus measurements.
   Ans: VenusMeasure;

begin
   Ans := Size( Rect1 );
end UseGIOEx2;
```

I am new to Ada. I am not sure why "with" is used in the generic .ads file (I think it has something to do with "*" and "Put" already being defined). My understanding is that any procedure/function declared in the .ads file needs to be defined in the body .adb file, but here the ones with "with" are defined in the actual program .adb file. After clarification, I am sure I can write my "or" overload! Thanks!

Comment: function "or" (a,b : my_integer) return boolean is begin ... end "or";

Comment: right but how would this look in the .ads file? do I say "with function "or"(a,b integer) return integer;"? and then write the code for it in the package body? @BrianDrummond

Comment: Same as any other function in a .ads file. Presumably you're putting these operators and related type decls in a package, right?

Comment: It's just a function whose name happens to be `"or"` rather than an identifier. Do you know how to write an ordinary function? (There's no `with`.)

Comment: I added some more info to the question that may better spell out my confusion. Thanks for you guys responses! @BrianDrummond

Comment: I added some more info to the question that may better spell out my confusion. Thanks for you guys responses! @KeithThompson

Comment: That's a completely different question. `with` in the generic specification indicates that the instantiation requires a function with a matching signature, to "customise" the generic to a specific task when you instantiate it.

Comment: The generic Package `GIOEx` is like a template with "code blanks" in it. In your case, the blanks would likely be in its body: The part between `generic` and `packages`  has both the "names" and the specifics for the different blanks. Creating and instance of the generic, such as `MyVenusRectangle`, you supply "actual code" for filling the blanks. (This shows the "sides" of a generic.) Also, for doing that your main program needs to known the template, so how is the latter introduced to the main program?

Comment: Also consider bitwise operations using modular types, examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18365473/230513).