# Ada - Boolean Arrays

Tags: ada

I want to code this picture [image]

The terminal should show this:

For DS2:

Type your data: **viDIn fJFN1 r1f29 M6YFu LDuWG fxFQ6 FkaSL JCGiq niVGg wLAUK**

-- User types in data displayed in BOLD TEXT

Your data: viDIn fJFN1 r1f29 M6YFu LDuWG fxFQ6 FkaSL JCGiq niVGg wLAUK

So I'm having trouble with the boolean expressions.

This is my approach

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Array is
   
   type Array_Inner_Type is
      array (5..9) of String(1..5);
     
   type Boolean_Type is 
      array (False..True) of Array_Inner_Type;
   
   MyArray : Boolean_Type;

   procedure Get(MyArray : out Boolean_Type) is 
   begin
      for I in True..False loop
         Get(MyArray(I));
      end loop;
   end Get;
    
end Array;
```

Once I get no errors in my terminal I believe I could solve this problem but so far I'm getting errors it is due to my for loop. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Add the error message to the question.

Comment: I solved the problem! It was a pity though :P

Comment: See also [*Bitwise Operations in Ada*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18365473/230513).

Comment: If your compiler didn’t point out that `array` is a reserved word, it’s a rotten compiler. Your `for` loop never executes (`True` .. `False` is an empty range). There’s no operation `Get` which takes an `Array_Inner_Type` as a parameter. That’s at a first glance.

Comment: @leun Your code has a number of semantic and syntax errors. Once changing the procedure name, from Array to Array_Test for example, other errors will show up during compilation like missing begin...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what all those strings are supposed to mean, but I'd be tempted to approach this as

```
subtype Word is String (1 .. 5);

type Funny_Map is array (Boolean, 5 .. 9) of Word;

Map : Funny_Map;
```